# Get name of parent parent folder

Tags: php

How do I get the name of the parent folder of the parent folder in php?

Example: /var/www/test/test2/index.php

In the index.php how do I get the name of the /test/ folder?

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`dirname()`](https://php.net/dirname) function.

Comment: Except that will give him `test2` not `test`..

Comment: why test? the parent folder of path `/var/www/test/test2/index.php` is test2

Comment: @lenswipe As of PHP 7.0, you can use `dirname($path, 2)` to get the parent's parent. On earlier version, you can just do `dirname(dirname($path))`

Comment: `dirname($path, 2)` should also be possible in php version 4, 5 and 7 @rickdenhaan

Comment: @RaymondNijland Nope, before 7.0 it will give a "dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given" warning

Comment: Thought I might as well post it as an answer

Comment: @rickdenhaan `dirname($path, 2)`  if i look into the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php there is nothing that indicaties level parameter is a PHP 7 only parameter

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes there is, in the changelog: "7.0.0 Added the optional levels parameter."

Comment: changelog isn't a documentation link @rickdenhaan then the documentation is about that function is bad.

Comment: @rickdenhaan ...huh. TIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dirname()`](https://php.net/dirname) for this:

```
$path = "/var/www/test/test2/index.php";

// PHP 7.0 and up:
$parent_of_parent = dirname($path, 2);

// earlier versions:
$parent_of_parent = dirname(dirname($path));
```